# Server Error when visiting page with experience editor?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

A page renders fine when visiting it with `sc_mode=normal`, but I get a server error when visiting it with `sc_mode=normal`.

This is the error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Utils.WebUtility.FixEmptyPlaceholders(String layout) +362
   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Utils.WebUtility.RenderLayout(Item item, HtmlTextWriter output, String siteName, String deviceId) +40
   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.PageExtender.RibbonWebControl.DoRender(HtmlTextWriter output) +619
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControl.RenderAsText() +225
   Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.RenderPageExtenders.SpeakRibbon.RenderPageEditorSpeakExtender.Render(TextWriter writer) +124
   Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.RenderPageExtenders.RenderPageExtendersProcessor.Process(RenderPageExtendersArgs args) +62
   (Object , Object[] ) +73
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +468
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +21
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +191
   Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.PageExtenderResponseFilter.GetExtendersHtml() +157
   Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.PageExtenderResponseFilter.get_ExtendersHtml() +30
   Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.Request.RequestEnd.AddPageExtenders.Process(RequestEndArgs args) +189
   (Object , Object[] ) +73
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +468
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +21
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +191
   Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +131
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +392
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +194
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +127
```

What is is a likely cause?

Comment: Could it be a difference in master and web database? Did you try a full site publish?

Answer (score 0):

These error is telling you that you have rendering which is without placeholder defined and that one is causing the error.